# Birational Invariants

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a smooth rational variety of dimension $n$. We have $\dim H^0(X,\Omega_X^p) = \dim H^0(\mathbb{P}^n,\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^n}^p)$ for any $p$. These are Hodge numbers. I know that we can not expect an equality for the sections of the sheaves $\Omega_X^p(k)$.

However, is it true that if $p < n$ then $\dim H^0(X,\Omega_X^p(k)) = 0$ if and only if $\dim H^0(\mathbb{P}^n,\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^n}^p(k))=0$ ?

Comment: Did you mean to write that $h^0(X,\Omega^p_X)$ equals $0$, which equals $h^0(\mathbb{P}^n,\Omega^p_{\mathbb{P}^n})$?  Also, have you chosen a finite morphism $f:X\to \mathbb{P}^n$ to compare $H^0(\mathbb{P}^n,\Omega^p_{\mathbb{P}^n}(k))$ and $H^0(X,\Omega^p_X(k))$?  If so, the statement is false already $p=1,k=1$ for a conic $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$.  The statement is also false for $p=1, k = 2$ for a linear projection of a smooth quadric surface $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$.  Perhaps this extends to quadric hypersurfaces of every dimension . . .

Comment: Typo correction: in the second example above, $p$ should be $2$.  Also, now I realize that probably you want to choose a rational transformation $X\supseteq U \xrightarrow{f} \mathbb{P}^n$.  For a smooth quadric hypersurface $X\subset \mathbb{P}^{n+1}$, linear projection from a point of $X$ gives such $f$.  Always, for $p=n$ and $k=n$, $h^0(X,\Omega^n_X(n))$ is nonzero, yet $h^0(\mathbb{P}^n,\Omega^n_{\mathbb{P}^n}(n))$ equals zero.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write $p < n$. I corrected the question. For a quadric hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n$ with $n\leq 5$ and for a cubic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ it's ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not true, even after the modifications.  Begin with a Veronese surface $X = v_2(\mathbb{P}^2) \subset \mathbb{P}^5$, i.e., $$ X = \{ [x_0^2,x_0x_1,x_0x_2,x_1^2,x_1x_2,x_2^2] \in \mathbb{P}^5 | [x_0,x_1,x_2]\in \mathbb{P}^2 \} = $$ $$\{ [y_{2,0,0},y_{1,1,0},y_{1,0,1},y_{0,2,0},y_{0,1,1},y_{0,0,2}] \in \mathbb{P}^5 | y_Iy_J - y_Ky_L = 0 \},   $$ where the relations range over all $4$-tuples $(I,J,K,L)$ of elements in $\{(2,0,0),\dots,(0,0,2)\}$ such that $I+J$ equals $K+L$.  Now form the linear birational equivalence, $$ f : X \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^2, \ [y_I] \mapsto [y_{1,1,0},y_{1,0,1},y_{0,1,1}]. $$  The maximal domain of definition of $f$ is $v_2(U)$ for the open subscheme $$U=\mathbb{P}^2 \setminus \{ [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1] \}.$$  The rational transformation $f$ is usually called the "standard Cremona transformation".  In particular, $f^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1)$ is isomorphic to $v_2^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^5}(1)$, and this is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(2)|_U$.  In particular, even though $h^0(\mathbb{P}^2,\Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1))$ equals $0$, $h^0(X,\Omega^1_X\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} f^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1))$ is nonzero.

The point is, because the group of birational automorphisms of every rational variety is so large, the invertible sheaves $f^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^d}(k)$ can take on many different values.